# Fecth data of specific tag from xml using xml.etree

Tags: python-3.x, xml, xml.etree

I am trying to fetch the **names** from an xml data which looks somewhat like this :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Major Version</key><integer>1</integer>
    <key>Minor Version</key><integer>1</integer>
    <dict>
        <key>369</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Track ID</key><integer>369</integer>
            <key>Name</key><string>Another One Bites The Dust</string>
            <key>Artist</key><string>Queen</string>
        </dict>
        <key>371</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Track ID</key><integer>371</integer>
            <key>Name</key><string>Asche Zu Asche</string>
            <key>Artist</key><string>Rammstein</string>
        </dict>
```

I am trying the following code which gives me the text value of `<key>` tag . I need the text value of second tag considering the text value of first tag is **Name** .
So the required output is **Another One Bites The Dust** and **Asche Zu Asche**

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    stuff = ET.parse(fname)
    all = stuff.findall('dict/dict/dict')
    for item in all:
      for child in item :
        if child.tag == 'key' and child.text == 'Name':
           print(child.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it with ET, try this:

```
all = stuff.findall('dict/dict')
for item in all:
    children = item.findall('.//key')
    for child in children:
        if child.text=="Name":
            print(item.find('.//string').text)
```

The easiest way to do this is to use lxml instead of xml.etree, since lxml has better xpath support. With that, it's very simple:

```
from lxml import etree
stuff = ET.parse(fname)
all = stuff.xpath('//dict/dict/key[.="Name"]/following-sibling::*[1]')
for a in all:
    print(a.text)
```

In both cases, the output is:

```
Another One Bites The Dust
Asche Zu Asche
```